# AppBarLayout cannot scroll

Tags: android

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    style="@style/AppTheme.AppBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/appbar_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        style="@style/AppTheme.ToolBar"
        >
        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/halfblack"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorPrimary"

        >

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_hotpost"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
```

when I use this layout,AppBarLayout cannot scroll,I think the key of this problem is that I set windowTranslucentNavigation to true; How to make it when I still want the navigation be transluncet.

If I set the appBarLayout  "android:fitsSystemWindows="true",the AppBar just show half although at this time, it can scroll.
[appbar show half when enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLYRM.png)

[translucent navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0sGs.png)

Comment: You should use RecyclerView inside of your fragments

Comment: Of course,there is a RecyclerView in the fragmet layout , and it is in the viewpager.@adnbsr

Comment: in the styles.xml add item as:  <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>